# Upload text file to parse multiple model data

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload

Say I have a table `objects`:

```
CREATE TABLE objects (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    someinfo VARCHAR(255),
);
```

And a text file like this:

```
name,someinfo
"firstname","firstinfo"
"secondname","secondinfo"
...
```

How can I upload this text file in CakePHP to process the data and create the objects? The processing isn't the problem, I've got that covered. I'm not sure how to upload the file however.

Note: the files can be up to 300MB in size.

***EDIT***
I've tried to use `LOAD DATA INFILE` as dogmatic69 suggested, using this code:

```
$filefullname = $this->request->data['File']['file']['tmp_name'];
debug($filefullname);
$query = 'LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY INFILE "'.$filefullname.'" INTO TABLE agencies FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY """" LINES TERMINATED BY "\r" IGNORE 1 LINES';
$this->Agency->query($query);
```

However, I get the following output:

```
'C:\Windows\Temp\phpB413.tmp'
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 29 File 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\WindowsTempphpB413.tmp' not found (Errcode: 2)
SQL Query: LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY INFILE "C:\Windows\Temp\phpB413.tmp" INTO TABLE agencies FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY """" LINES TERMINATED BY "\r" IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Comment: options to upload a file with cakephp are the same as with php - you submit a form, use an applet or (e.g.) ftp the file to the server. i.e. If you know how to upload a file with php - you know how to upload a file with cakephp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from @Mark has only covered a small portion of what you need so here is more:

Btw [savants upload plugin](https://github.com/josegonzalez/upload) is probably more popular than what was linked. Going by the stars and forks its roughly *twice* as popular as uploadpack.

You need to parse the csv data into a cake format that is good for saving. [here](https://github.com/infinitas/infinitas/tree/dev/Core/Data/Lib/Csv) is a few classes for doing just that. Look at the [tests](https://github.com/infinitas/infinitas/tree/dev/Core/Data/Test/Case/Lib/Csv) for usage

With huge amounts of data you want to avoid `saveAll()` as it will create one insert for every row. Use [this](https://github.com/infinitas/infinitas/blob/dev/Core/Data/Model/Behavior/BigDataBehavior.php) for some ideas on doing bulk inserts.

Honestly if you are importing 300MB CSV files you should be using MySQL `LOAD DATA INFILE` which is much faster. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm testing the `LOAD DATA INFILE` without moving the uploaded file, but errors occur. See the edited question.

Comment: The files have to be readble for mysql, I would think the uploaded file is only readable by your webserver.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be best off using a 3rd party library, the most popular being : uploadpack  : https://github.com/szajbus/uploadpack